# How to track entire folder with Orangedox for Dropbox

Tags: orangedox

Can I share a whole folder with tracking enabled? I know I can share and track individual files, that's no problem; but, if I'm trying to send the client 50 photos I can't efficiently send them 50 different links the track when they downloaded them.

Answer (score 1):

I checked the same in current version and noticed that the folder share and track is not available. It is available for file level only but if you wanted to track folder sharing in dropbox you can use google following the below steps.

- get folder share link from dropbox
- shorten that using Google "http://goo.gl/"
- Always use the shortened version of the URL/link when posting it on the web or giving it to access
- As long as you logged in to the Google account you can see the count of link usage.

Answer (score 0):

Vembu is correct, our current version doesn't support folders .. yet.  We will be releasing a new version in the next few weeks that will include folder sharing & file preview metrics (not just downloads) as well as a slew of other features.

Once this version is available you should be able to share out a folder with a client with all their 50 photos, then be able to see if they previewed each photo and/or downloaded it.

In the intern you could zip the pictures up into a zip file and then track the zip file download

EDIT (Jan 8th 2015):

Our latest version of Pro now allows you to track folders .. see when a file was downloaded or previewed within your shared folders